# How do I make custom hover labels? Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hover, label, mousehover

Is there a way to have a hover box display something other than "Series "POSITION" Point "2/24/2012" Data Label"? I would like to make a custom hover label. I know there are similar posts, but I am looking for a simpler solution. The related posts I felt were trying to do something much more difficult than mine. I simply want data on a chart from columns A and B, but want to display information from column C when hovered over a data label.

I have tried:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If X > 10 And X < Label1.Width - 10 And Y > 10 And Y < Label1.Height - 10 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

But this hasn't worked yet. The original poster said to mess with the 10 value, but I haven't seen any improvement. Also, how do I know which label is "Label1."?

Thanks!
Jaxon

Comment: This appears to be code related to a Form control on a UserForm object, where `Label1` is an Label object on the UserForm.  No amount of tinkering with this code will do what you want it to do.

Comment: Okay thank you! That makes sense now. Is there a way to reference the data labels if I separate it into a different chart sheet? Can you think of a code I can use to customize the hover box text?

Comment: I have seen that. As far as I could tell, that would permanently add labels to the data. I just wanted the data to show up when I hover over the point or data label. For instance: data label says, "Issue #13". When you hover over it, the hover box says, "Mike Tyson fought Rocky in the woods over who is going to eat the bear that Chuck Norris killed with his hands." The hover box would be too much to put as a data label, but I still want that information linked to the data point somehow.

Comment: pnuts, it is a great resource for knowing how to reference other data. For instance, if I could change the line stating "ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _True" to "...(Counter).HasHoverBox = _True" or something to that effect, it could work. I just don't know vba syntax enough to know how to reference objects like data labels, etc.

Comment: See this solution. It is exactly what you want **IF** it is acceptable to use chart sheets instead of ordinary worksheets. These expose some additional events specidically pertaining to mouse movement etc.   http://www.databison.com/interactive-chart-in-vba-using-mouse-move-event/

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I haven't been able to find that in my searches. I will be messing with that tonight!

Comment: It is working great! Thank you both for the input. I will be ironing out some kinks.

Comment: We don't write "solved" here in the titles.  Post an answer instead or delete the question.